# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000 DirectX 10

Tags: crash, directx, access-violation

I am trying to get a render target for my swap chain using DirectX 10.  For some reason, when I add in the GetBuffer line, it spits out errors. Here's my file:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <d3d10.h>
#include <D3DX10.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "d3d10")

//WINDOWS MAIN FUNCTION
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);

//WINDOW PROCEDURE FUNCTION
//RESPONDS TO EVENTS
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

//Global variables

//The main window class name.
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("virhackapp");

// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("VirHack");

HINSTANCE hInst;
//DirectX Vars
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC *SwapChain;
IDXGISwapChain **ppSwapChain;
ID3D10Device **device;
void **ppSurface;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //LAST THREE ARE OUTPUTS, SEE VARS ABOVE
    D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, D3D10_SDK_VERSION, D3D10_SDK_VERSION, SwapChain, ppSwapChain, device);
    (*ppSwapChain)->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D10Texture2D), ppSurface);

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"), _T("virhackapp"), NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    hInst = hInstance;
    //The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
    //szWindowClass:  The name of the app
    //szTitle: the text taht appears in the title bar
    //WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of the window to create
    //CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position(x,y)
    //500,100: initial size(width, length)
    //NULL: the parent of this window
    //NULL: this application does not have a menu bar
    //hInstance: thie first parameter from WinMain
    //NULL: not used in this application
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 100, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"), _T("virhackapp"), NULL);
        return 1;
    }


    //DISPLAYS WINDOW
    //The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    //hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    //nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    //MESSAGE LOOP THAT SENDS TO WndProc
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //WM_PAINT: app recieves this message when part of its displayed window must be updated. (When the window is first displayed, all of it must be updated)
    //To handle WM_PAINT, first call BeginPaint, then handle all logic to lay out text, buttons, and other controls
    //Then call EndPaint
    //Use TextOut to display a string
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Hello, World!");

    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        //Here the application is laid out.
        //For right now, displays "Hello, World!"
        //in the top left corner.
        //Graphics are done here
        TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
        //End application specific layout section
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The erroneous line is here:

(*ppSwapChain)->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D10Texture2D), ppSurface);

I suspect this is happening because my CreateDeviceAndSwapChain is not successfully completing, but I have no idea why.  Here is the actual error report:

```
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Will\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\VirHack\Debug\VirHack.exe', Symbols loaded.
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Norton\{0C55C096-0F1D-4F28-AAA2-85EF591126E7}\NAV_20.2.0.19\Definitions\BASHDefs\20130620.001\UMEngx86.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10core.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detoured.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VirHack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
First-chance exception at 0x00831056 in VirHack.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x778e15de in VirHack.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
The program '[10756] VirHack.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Comment: First check the result of `D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain`. I'll bet it is failing. Also, for those output pointers, you don't just declare and pass a `**`. You need to take the address of, for example, a `ID3D10Device *`.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob at this.... what do you mean by take the address of the ID3D10Device *?  And how do I check the result of D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain?

Comment: D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain returns a HResult, see if it equals S_OK (0) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205278(v=vs.85).aspx